# C# initialize a generic type using a strategy-pattern-provided constructor

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, strategy-pattern

I have a class that operates on a generic type:

```
public class Operation<I> where I : IAnimal
```

and I define `IAnimal` as the following:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

I define a class as the following:

```
public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; private set; }

    public Dog(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

If I want to use `Dog` in the `Operation` class, since the `Dog` class does not have a parameter-less constructor, I leverage strategy pattern as the following:

```
public interface IConstructor
{
    IAnimal Construct(string name);
}

public class DogConstructor : IConstructor
{
    IAnimal Construct(string name)
    {
        return new Dog(name);
    }
}

public class Operation<I> where I : IAnimal
{
    public Operation() : this(new DogConstructor())
    { }

    public Operation(IConstructor constructor)
    {
        I animal = constructor.Construct("myDog"); // <<<<<<<< Error here!
    }
}
```

At the market place, I receive `Cannot implicitly convert type 'IAnimal' to 'I'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Of course if I case like `I animal = (I)constructor.Construct("myDog");`, all works. However, I am wondering why do I need to cast while I have `where I : IAnimal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I am wondering why do I need to cast while I have where `I : IAnimal`.

Yes, you did guarantee that `I` will be a subclass of `IAnimal` or `IAnimal` itself, but what would `Construct` return? `Construct` might return a different subclass from `I`.

Whenever you are using generics, you should remember that the generic parameter types are provided by the client code of your class/method, not the class/method. Here you are forcing `I` to be `Dog` by using a `DogConstructor` if not arguments were passed in. If you are doing this, then it probably means that generics is not suitable here. Try removing it:

```
public class Operation
{
    public Operation() : this(new DogConstructor())
    { }

    public Operation(IConstructor constructor)
    {
        IAnimal animal = constructor.Construct("myDog");
    }
}
```

Now if you insist on using generics, you can't just assume a `DogConstructor` by default, and `IConstructor` should probably be generic as well:

```
public interface IConstructor<T> where I: IAnimal
{
    T Construct(string name);
}

public class DogConstructor : IConstructor<Dog>
{
    Dog Construct(string name)
    {
        return new Dog(name);
    }
}

public class Operation<I> where I : IAnimal
{
    public Operation(IConstructor<I> constructor)
    {
        I animal = constructor.Construct("myDog");
    }
}

public class DogOperation: Operation<Dog> {
    public DogOperation() : base(new DogConstructor()) {}
}
```

> since the Dog class does not have a parameter-less constructor

Another solution might be to constrain `I` so that it must have a parameterless constructor, and add one to `Dog`:

```
class Operation<I> where I : IAnimal, new() {
```

Comment: I decide to implement `<I>` for the constructor. I cannot allow parameterless construct because that can lead to mutable objects in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is compiler does not know the what Class you are going to pass in place of I. Suppose you create another class Cat derived from Animal similar to Dog. Now you pass Cat in Operation in place of I, which is fine as per the code. But constructor.Construct("myDog") is returning Dog which is a sibling of Cat, and can not be parsed into Cat. So error will come. See the code

```
public interface IAnimal
{
        string Name { get; }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Dog(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Cat(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
}

public class Operation<I> where I : IAnimal
{
        public Operation() : this(new DogConstructor())
        { }

        public Operation(IConstructor constructor)
        {
            I animal = constructor.Construct("myDog"); // <<<<<<<< Error here!
        }
}
```

Check the below code. You are passing Cat and you want it to be mapped with Dog. That could not work.

```
public class XYZ
{
       public void MyMethod()
       {
            var obj = new Operation<Cat>();
       }
}
```

If you know it will constructor.Construct("myDog") returns animal then replace I with IAnimal. That way compiler is sure about the reference in which returned object from constructor.Construct("myDog") to be set

```
public class Operation<I> where I : IAnimal
{
        public Operation() : this(new DogConstructor())
        { }

        public Operation(IConstructor constructor)
        {
            IAnimal animal = constructor.Construct("myDog"); // <<<<<<<< Error here!
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no guarantee that your `IConstructor` will return the same class as `I`. You could have an `Operation<Cat>`, and pass to the constructor a `DogConstructor`.

You can solve this by making the `IConstructor` generic too, and make the Operation constructor to receive an `IConstructor<I>`.

Answer (score 1):

i faced same problem and i used Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, params object[] args)

```
static void Main()
{
    var operation = new Operation<Dog>("Jack");
    Console.WriteLine(operation.Animal.Name);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Dog()
    {
    }

    public Dog(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Operation<T> where T : IAnimal, new()
{
    public T Animal { get; private set; }

    public Operation()
    {
        Animal = new T();
    }

    public Operation(params object[] args)
    {
        Animal = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    }
}
```

Comment: [I might be wrong] activator does not seem strongly typed to me.